# CSS Double border with h1 and span

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, border

I want overlap the "border-bottom" of `<span>` above the border-bottom of `<h1>`. In Google Chrome and Opera works fine but in Firefox there is a difference of 1 pixel. I have tried many methods but always looks different in Firefox. Is there any way to improve this in Firefox or using other methods do not necessarily span?.

Sorry for my bad english :(.

My HTML:

```
<h1><span>My Title Test<span></h1>​
```

CSS:

```
h1 {
 border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; 

}
span{
border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
display: inline;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9WuBk/

Comment: I see the same result in Firefox 11 as Chrome and Opera...

Comment: I see it in Firefox 11: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg641/scaled.php?server=641&filename=capturadepantalla201204.png&res=medium

Comment: Ok. What I want is this (as I see in Chrome and Opera): http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg42/scaled.php?server=42&filename=capturadepantalla201204j.png&res=medium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline borders don't typically flush themselves with their parent block borders. Given how different browsers render inline content differently, this ends up being inconsistent.

You can work around this specific case by making your `<span>` an inline block to normalize the position of the borders, then giving your `<span>` a `-1px` bottom margin to shift it down (or rather, pull the `<h1>` border up):

```
h1 {
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
span {
    border-bottom:1px solid #000; 
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:-1px;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/9WuBk/3)

Comment: It works perfect! Thanks! I know it's not the best way, but I don't know of another technique to achieve the same effect as I want.